# Unions of closed sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification, proof-explanation

Let $\bar{A}$ be the closure of $A$. Let $B_n = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i$ for positive integer $n$. I want to show that $\bar{B}_n = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}\bar{A}_i$.

I am thinking if $x$ is a limit point of $B_n$, if $x \in \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i$ then clearly $x \in \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}\bar{A}_i$. If $x \notin \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i$ then suppose $x$ is not a limit point of any $A_i$. This contradicts that $x$ is a limit point of $B_n$ so then $x \in \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}\bar{A}_i$. So $B_n \subset  \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}\bar{A}_i$. I think the reverse inclusion is straightforward.

For an infinite union $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}\bar{A}_i$ does not contain $\bar{B}_n$ because a limit point $x \in B_n$ may for each neighborhood $N_r(x)$ intersect a different $A_i$ and there are infinite $A_i$ so none of them necessarily have $x$ as a limit point.

Comment: "This contradicts that" Yes, but why?

Comment: For each $A_i$ find a radius $r_i$ such that $N_{r_i}(x)$ does not intersect $A_i$. Then let $l=min\{r_i\}$  and $N_l(x)$ does not intersect any $A_i$ so does not intersect $B_n$.

Comment: Yes thats nice. And yes the reverse is straightforward.

Comment: That was what I was missing, very good!

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is a limit point of $B_n = \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$, then for some $1\le i \le n$, $x$ is a limit point of $A_i$, for if this were *not* the case, for every $1 \le i \le n$ we have a ball $N_{r_i}(x)$ for some $r_i>0$, such that $N_{r_i} \cap A_i \subseteq \{x\}$, define $r=\displaystyle\min_{1 \le i \le n} r_i >0$ and note that $$N_r(x) \cap B_n = \bigcap_{i=1}^n N_{r_i}(x)  \cap B_n \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n (N_{r_i}(x) \cap A_i) \subseteq \{x\}$$

which contradicts that $X$ is a limit point of $B_n$, so the assumption was wrong.

Denoting the set of limit points of a set $A$ by $A'$ and using that $\overline{A}= A \cup A'$ we conclude:

$$\overline{B_n} = B_n \cup B_n' = \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i \cup \left( \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i \right)' = \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i \cup \bigcup_{i=1}^n A'_i = \bigcup_{i=1}^n (A_i \cup A_i') = \bigcup_{i=1}^n \overline{A_i}$$

And we're done.